# Using Vue 3 components in standard HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs3

We currently have a Vue 2 component library we are using in HTML pages without a Vue app. I am wanting to migrate it to Vue 3 as it is built using Vue 2.5 and an old webpack version, but am unable to find a way to use a Vue 3 component library the same way.

The current Vue 2 entry file is like:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Test from '../src/components/Test.vue';

Vue.component('test-component', Test);

new Vue({
  el: '#body'
});
```

An an example HTML file is

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="body">
      <div>This is in the HTML</div>
      <test-component></test-component>
    </div>
    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When opened in the browser, Vue replaces the html elements (e.g. `<test-component>`) with the Vue component.

The resulting HTML in the devtools is:

```html
<html><head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="body"><div>This is in the HTML</div> <div>Hello from the Vue component!</div></div>
    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
  

</body></html>
```

Having looked at the migration docs (https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/mount-changes.html etc), I tried making the equivalent entry file for Vue 3:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import Test from '../src/components/Test.vue';

const app = createApp();
app.component('test-component', Test);
app.mount('#body');
```

Which I am then compiling as a library bundle using Vite

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import analyze from 'rollup-plugin-analyzer';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
        define: {
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
        },
        build: {
                rollupOptions: {
                        plugins: [analyze()]
                },
                lib: {
                        entry: [
                                './lib/bundle.js'
                        ],
                        name: 'MagicComponents',
                        fileName: (format, entryName) => entryName + '.' + format + '.js'
                }
        }
})
```

But the instead of just replacing the html elements is it replacing all the innerHTML of the `#body` element, resulting in

```html
<html><head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="body"></div>
    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Is there a way to get Vue 3 to act the same way as Vue 2 (without exporting the Vue 3 components as web components)?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try this: `const app = createApp(Test)`